# struct inherit and initialize with base class

Tags: c++, c++11

Got the following scenario:

```
struct BaseInfo
{
  std::string name;
};

struct AddInfo : public BaseInfo
{
  std::string name2;
}
```

And i want to initialize `AddInfo with a BaseInfo` object.

```
std::vector<BaseInfo> base; // objects already inserted
std::vector<AddInfo> add(base);// <-- failed
```

the `AddInfo::name2` should be uninitialize, is there a simple way of doing this ? BaseInfo can have many members and i dont want to write a copy constuct :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<BaseInfo>` and `std::vector<AddInfo>` are unrelated types, so you cannot copy construct one from the other. What you can do is use the two iterator constructor to construct from the elements

```
std::vector<AddInfo> add(base.begin(), base.end());
```

This will construct an `AddInfo` object in `add` from each `BaseInfo` object in `base. But that assumes an`AddInfo`can be constructed from a`BaseInfo`, in other words, this must be possible:

```
BaseInfo b;
AddInfo a(b);
```

You can achieve this by giving `AddInfo` a suitable constructor:

```
AddInfo(const BaseInfo& base) : BaseInfo(base) {  }
```

See this [working example](http://ideone.com/UstvGu).

Comment: do i need to create a copy part for this ?

Comment: @Roby Yes, if you don't have one already, you need to provide a suitable constructor.

Comment: this works, thanks, but why it is possible with iterator's, not with the hole object ?

Comment: @Roby I expanded the answer. I hope it is clear now.